# Is this sentence correct grammatically? "I want to buy a car, especially a red one made in America."

Tags: pronouns

I'm a Japanese learner of English.

I have a question about an indefinite pronoun "one."

Can "one" is used as follows?

a(n) + an adjective + one + an adjective phrase (or an adjective clause)

Also, can "ones" is used as follows?

an adjective + ones + an adjective phrase (or an adjective clause)

For example, is the following sentence correct grammatically?

I want to buy a car, especially a red one made in America.

Comment: Your proposed sentence looks fine to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of "one" here is perfect. But "especially" is the wrong word in this case. It sounds like there are several different cars and you want to buy *all* of them, *especially* the American one.  You probably really only want to buy one car, and so "preferably" would be a better choice.

We can also phrase it as "an American car" rather than "a car made in America": both are acceptable but the first one is more idiomatic, unless you really mean the place of manufacture/assembly (for example a car from a Japanese company which was assembled in America).

> I want to buy a car, preferably a red American one.

Comment: Or with a slightly different emphasis, ***specifically*** rather than ***preferably*** might be closer to what the OP wants to convey. In which context, ***specifically*** might well imply the speaker has no interest whatsoever in buying any other kind of car, whereas ***preferably*** strongly implies speaker would consider a blue American car, or a red Japanese one, for example, if his ***exact specification*** can't be met.